# Pandas - very slow performance when using stack(), groupby() and apply()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am having a very slow performance when calling stack, groupby and apply for a large dataframe in Pandas (1498829 rows). The code gives the differences of pairs (with this I mean the difference of xx's for all i2 at every i1).

**The part of the code that is running slow is:**

```py
def get_diff(x):
    teams = x.index.get_level_values(1)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(x[:,None]-x[None,:],
                       columns = teams.values,
                       index=teams.values).stack()
    return tmp[tmp.index.get_level_values(0)!=tmp.index.get_level_values(1)]

new_df = df.groupby('i1').xx.apply(get_diff).to_frame()
```

And the full code (with the data) is:

```py
import pandas as pd
from random import randint


# data (it takes some time to create [less than 1 minute in my computer])
data1   = [[[[randint(0, 100) for i in range(randint(1, 2))] for i in range(randint(1, 3))] for i in range(5000)] for i in range(100)]
data2   = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (i1, i2, i3, i4, x4)
        for (i1, x1) in enumerate(data1)
        for (i2, x2) in enumerate(x1)
        for (i3, x3) in enumerate(x2)
        for (i4, x4) in enumerate(x3)
    ],
    columns = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'xx']
)
data2.drop(['i3', 'i4'], axis=1, inplace = True)
df   = data2.set_index(['i1', 'i2']).sort_index()


## conflicting part of the code ##
def get_diff(x):
    teams = x.index.get_level_values(1)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(x[:,None]-x[None,:],
                       columns = teams.values,
                       index=teams.values).stack()
    return tmp[tmp.index.get_level_values(0)!=tmp.index.get_level_values(1)]

new_df = df.groupby('i1').xx.apply(get_diff).to_frame()
```

***If you could elaborate on the code to make it more efficient and execute faster, I would really appreciate it.***

Comment: So whenever `i1 != i2` you want `xx-xx`?

Comment: I remembered having the similar problem, which I solved similarly to what you did. I just let it run for awhile and save the result if I needed it in the next run.

Comment: The code gives you the difference of the xx's for all i2 at every i1. In this sense the code gives the differences of pairs.The code is working, so I just need to improve the performance. You can try with a smaller dataframe to figure out what is doing